# How to align Calendar Icon to left in antd DatePicker or RangePicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, components, antd, daterangepicker

**Calendar Icon is aligned to the right of DatePicker and RangePicker by default.**

How to change its position to the left.

Refer to the image below to understand the expected behavior.

I have tried all the props `nextIcon` `prevIcon` `suffixIcon` `superNextIcon` `superPrevIcon` but didn't achieve the expected behavior.

Docs: https://ant.design/components/date-picker/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working code for both DatePicker and RangePicker**

This answer is an update on the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71936328/14853666) which works fine with the date picker but not with the range picker.

The current issue with `flex-direction: row-reverse` for RangePicker is with the order ( Icon, End Date, Start Date ). Refer image below
[image]

We can solve this issue by assigning `order:-1` to the icon.

```
.ant-picker .ant-picker-input span.ant-picker-suffix,
.ant-picker.ant-picker-range span.ant-picker-suffix {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  order: -1;
}
```

Final UI:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following styles to align icon to from right to left.

```
.ant-picker .ant-picker-input,
.ant-picker.ant-picker-range {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.ant-picker .ant-picker-input span.ant-picker-suffix,
.ant-picker.ant-picker-range span.ant-picker-suffix {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
flex-direction: row-reverse
```

to input css class